# Can I log when the message arrival rate exceeds the message delivery rate in postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, e-mailrelay

I am trying to implement a MTA, on reading documentation of the postfix I found a parameter 'in_flow_delay' whose description in sort says 'Time to pause before accepting a new message, when the message arrival rate exceeds the message delivery rate.'. How can I log or receive email notifications when such thing happens?

Based on the answers and comments I guess indeed postfix will log when such a condition arise. But someone can clarify how can I test this logging now (i.e. when the delivery rates are under control)?

Also just for conformance, I'd like to ask if I am wrong in considering that this condition measures congestion in the queue (actually accepted emails after access restrictions) while the stressed condition in postfix measures the incoming connection overflow (like in case of DDoS attacks).

Comment: It will log this event already, you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix has logging implemented by default in its design. Depending on your Linux distribution it either logs to journalctl using systemd logging(`journalctl -u postfix`),or using syslog or rsyslog to a seperate log file in /var/log.
You might need to tweak the logging level a bit too get there right info.

Answer (score 0):

This is very specific. As was said in a comment with the normal log level this event should appear in logs. To be notified by e-mail when this happens you should script a log-parser and trigger mail when this event appears in logs.

Comment: Sorry for the stupidity, I just haven't seen it in the log yet so was unsure if it will it even appear if any thing goes down or will I have to write a separate script using qshape for it that's why I asked.  Also just for conformance I'd like to ask that if I am wrong in considering this condition measures congestion in queue while the stressed condition in postfix measure the smtpd incoming connection overflow (like in case of DDoS attacks);.

Comment: Just with rsyslog sending your logs to a central syslog collector (kiwi syslog) or monitoring system, can also be in the cloud. Way better than overloading your mailbox

Comment: @Turdie Thanks for suggesting kiwi. But actually, I want to get notified for such conditions; I'll need to create a filter for alerts thus if I can see the log line beforehand by simulating it'll do. And anyway I'll do it in a test setup, not a production one.

Comment: There are also systems like graylog which have built in alert templates or wazuh also. You can then set an email alert in graylog using a notification channel. Those alert templates have built-in filters for critical log messages in the postfix logs, according to best practices for event log management